# How to detect if any environment variable has changed? Python - CPanel

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpanel

I have a Python app running in Cpanel. I would like to detect if any environment variables has changed in the initial variable table, i want app to restart. I couldn't figure it out. can anyone give a hand?

I couldnt find out the way to do that.

Comment: How is an environment variable going to change without you knowing about it?

Comment: @omer your python app makes a copy of the environment when it starts. The only changes to it's environment after that point are from within the app itself.

Comment: @jeff thanks, i see there is not a way to find it out. I will edit the app to to change the variables after the app started then.